# Replacing a character between numbers in UNIX

Tags: regex, sed

I have a  file in UNIX which has a character in the time stamp

```
2016-06-24T14:00:00.1000000;True;
```

I want to replace the `T` in the time stamp with blank. I used `sed` but it didn't work.

```
sed -i.bak 's/[0-9]T[0-9]/ /g' filename.csv
```

When I run the script it is converting the output to:

```
2016-06-2 4:00:00.1000000;True;
```

It's lost the 4 before the T and the 1 after it.

Comment: In future, please note that you can edit your own question and should add information such as the actual output (and a description of the expected output) to the question, rather than adding a comment.  I've moved the material this time, but in future, please do it yourself.  (Don't destroy your question with such edits, especially if you've got answers that address the question as originally written, but adding extra information is almost always fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture digits before and after `T`. Then, you do not need `g (global substitution).`

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)T\([0-9]\)/\1 \2/' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `tr` with pipe:

```
cat filename.csv |  tr 'T' ''
```

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons: The `tr` utility won't allow you to transliterate `T` into an empty string. Use its `-d` option for that. Doing `tr -d "T"` would delete *all* Ts, not just the first one. Test your solutions before posting.

Comment: Sorry men,  i'm new  in this. I will follow your advice

Comment: But, you can replace with space. You don't need `cat`. Use like: `tr 'T' ' ' < file`